# SVD for square matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

I already know the concept of SVD applyed on an mxn matrix. Eigen vectors can't exist for a non-square matrix, but singular-vectors can. My question is: does SVD on a square matrix relate to eigendecomposition in a way?

SVD:

$M=UEV^*$, where M is mxn, $U$ is mxm, $E$ is mxn and $V^*$ is nxn

Now if M is mxm, then: $U$ is mxm, $E$ is mxm and $V^*$ is also mxm, which resembles a lot the eigendecomposition (case where U=V).

Comment: Yes they're related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Relation_to_eigenvalue_decomposition

Comment: As the possible duplicate outlines, the notions are essentially the same for positive definite symmetric (or Hermitian) matrices and closely related for normal matrices (more generally).  Also the SVD of $M$ can be directly related to the eigendecompositions of $MM^*$ and $M^*M$, to follow your notation.